# Why does mypy not recognize that arguments to Mapping.get() are positional only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

The method `Mapping.get` takes no keyword arguments, they are positional only. Why is this not detected by mypy if misused?

```
$ mypy --command "a: str = dict(b='yes').get('a', default='no')"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan 13 2021, 15:21:08) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a: str = dict(b='yes').get('a', default='no')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: dict.get() takes no keyword arguments
```

There's a [PR](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/2497) from 2016 where the convention is introduced that arguments starting with two underscores are positional only for mypy. Is this convention simply not followed in such a basic type? I'm wondering why.

Note that [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) has been created 2018 has been just introduced with Python 3.8.

Comment: Is `dict.get` type-hinted? If not, `mypy` is just ignoring it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where built-ins are type hinted. The dict itself is implemented in C.

Comment: I don't either, which is why I can't provide a proper answer. :) If it is, there's probably a `.pyi` file somewhere in the CPython source that provides it. The behavior, though, suggests that it is not hinted in this way.

Comment: Builtin stubs are provided by the typeshed project (https://github.com/python/typeshed). Those for dict are in https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi but dict.get is inherited from Mapping in https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/typing.pyi .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many built-ins do not take keyword arguments, see this [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue8706), opened in 2010. The main reasons there are

- **overhead:** built-ins are implemented in C, and parsing either positional or keyword arguments comes with some computational overhead (although this seems to be alleviated [in the meantime](https://bugs.python.org/issue29029))
- **little added value:** typically, built-ins have reasonably small function signatures, so not having kwargs is not a big deal
- **no demand:** many built-ins are relatively old and around for a long time, w/o this being an issue in the past, which is historic evidence that there is no demand from devs to have kwargs
- **a lot of effort:** positional arguments can be renamed easily, their scope is limited to the implementation of the function itself, not on the callers; kwargs kind of become part of the language and need to be well thought out as they cannot be easily changed later

Thus, mypy *should* report the error, but it doesn't. As built-ins stubs are typed in typeshed, there is an [open bug report in the typeshed issue tracker at github](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5771).